# behavior of httpErrors with existingResponse Auto in web.config

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

I am looking for confirmation of observed but undocumented IIS 7.5 behavior since I am not able to find this behavior documented at MS site. I need  a way to pass through only custom exceptions thrown by using new Exception(), I have customErrors set to Off and the following in web.config

```
  <httpErrors existingResponse="Auto">
  <clear/>
</httpErrors>
```

I am not using TrySkipIisCustomErrors in my code at all but this seems to work as needed. System errors still behave like with "customErrors='On'" but my custom exceptions are going to my Ajax call where I parse it to show a message. 
This is my test webmethod:

```
public string Update(Models.CaseData appData, Models.CaseData appDataCache)
        {

            //Test 1.  trigger system error 
            var t = 0;
            var x = 1;
            var p = x / t;

            var sendEmail = IsModified(appData, appDataCache);

            //Test 2. Throw user defined error
            if (appDataCache != null && !sendEmail)
            {
                throw new Exception("Your changes do not require sending email. Are you sure you want to save these changes?".ToJsonError(type: "confirm"));
            }
        }
```

- Test 1 is division by zero
- Test 2 is my custom exception.

If I keep Test 1 I get generic message "There was a problem processing the request" from IIS but if I comment it out my custom exception from Test 2 is going to Ajax error handler.

That is exactly how I need IIS to behave but I am not sure if this IIS behavior is by design or I am hitting some kind of IIS bug that works in my favor, kind of hesitant to deliver it to production.

Please advise or help with providing another solution to pass through only custom exceptions.

Thank you.

Comment: This link provide the steps about how to bypass IIS error https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jun/01/bypassing-iis-error-messages-in-aspnet. Have you checked whether all configuration was set correctly?

Comment: config seems to be OK, but frankly I am not sure what could be incorrect config and just to be on the safe side I am now adding HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true to the webmethod even though it does not make any difference in my case, thanks for the link